# Keyboard is too stiff for me - any way to make it looser?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

Edit: I'm talking about scissor-type - and butterfly is worse, in my opinion.

In general, I feel that the keyboard of Mac (or here my main focus is actually MBP) is too stiff. Because I'm *too weak*, when I keep typing my fingers eventually start hurting.

This is the only reason why I keep using XPS, whose keys are very easy to type.

But because I want to completely switch to Mac, I'm looking for a way to make MBP's key looser, that is, less stiff. Is there anybody who has this kind of experience, or any successful result? I'm thinking like, for example, taking the key cover off the board and tweaking the spring(?) to make it weak or somethinkg like that.

Comment: What is the make and model of Mac laptop that you are using?

Comment: I really don't think you are going to find a solution to changing the MBP keyboard itself but you may find suggestions on external wired and wireless keyboards. The keys are low profile and have a very short throw (distance to push the key). It may not be that you are too weak but too strong. Striking the keys harder than necessary.  Butterfly keys had a lot of issues with debris getting under the keys and causing them to fail requiring more intense strikes to register a keypress. Apple will fix that for free if you have that problem.  But replacing the entire top case is required.

Comment: @NimeshNeema 15-inch, Mid 2015 (meaning the keyboard is scissor). It's a bit old but when I tried the latest MBP at the store my impression was the same.

Comment: @JamesBrickley oh, sorry. As I commented it's actually scissor (and butterfly is definitely not for me...)

Comment: I am seeing your comments only after posting the answer. I guess going with an external keyboard would be your best bet.

Answer (score 2):

> I feel that the keyboard of Mac (or here my main focus is actually MBP) is too stiff.

There is no reasonable way you can change the stiffness of a MacBooks keyboard. However depending on the model of the MacBook, the tactile feedback could differ. While the keyboard typing feel could argued to be subjective, a general perception is that the new Butterfly keyboards introduced in Late 2019 16" MacBook Pro and then eventually in the newer 2020 13" MacBook Pro and 2020 MacBook Air are easier to type on.

So if you are using one of the older MacBooks, you can consider buying a new one after you give the new Butterfly keyboard a try in a store.

Alternatively, you can also consider getting an external keyboard where you pick one as per your exact liking.

Answer (score 2):

Attempting to modify any MacBook keyboard is a costly mistake in my opinion and experience. Do anything but this.

- Run a Dell / HP / Microsoft and remote in for occasional macOS use
- Run an external keyboard if you need macOS - bluetooth is very good now, as is wired
  compatibility
- Get a Chromebook

When you break the scissors or butterfly, spare parts are expensive or low fidelity. Topcase repair is costly as batteries are integral and you can’t really get to the bottom of the keyboard without destroying your battery that also is expensive or low fidelity third party options when damaged.

Try to figure if you can let go of disappointment and enjoy a Mac or you have to take a stand and avoid Apple. I believe that changing the nature of the keyboard will be harder and less productive than changing your requirements or expectations.

Answer (score 1):

Might it be the case that you're actually hitting the keys too hard, and that is what is causing your fingers to hurt? The required downward force is very little, and it may just take a little while to accustom yourself to it.

Comment: That might be the case, but that wouldn't explain why xps doesn't hurt my fingers... I actually have another 30g keyweight keyboard (which basically means the keys are loosest), and it's a lot better than any Mac keyboard. (and no, please don't say "then just use it" - that would beat the portability.)